# Android custom ListView item with two buttons and TextView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with elements like this:
[ListView item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGmBx.png)
This is my component tree:
[Component Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQpS3.png)

I will change those two buttons with images, but how I could make that TextView would fill whole width? Because now it has a width specified in dp.

Comment: put your code here please

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: @Lukenzo use weight for that

Comment: why would you place textView in seperate linearLayout????

Comment: `how I could make that TextView would fill whole width?` Ever heard of `match_parent`?

Comment: add "android:layout_weight=1"

Comment: @sree `match_parent` works also in RelativeLayouts.

Comment: @Lukenzo Please see my answer below.

Comment: @FerdousAhamed Thank you, works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use extra `LinearLayout`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#e0e0e0">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteEexerciseBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Delete"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editEexerciseBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/deleteEexerciseBtn"
        android:text="Edit"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exerciseName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editEexerciseBtn"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is a Large text with fill width"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `android:width="match_parent"` for your `TextView`.

However, you could also solve this with setting `layout_weight` attribute for each `LinearLayout` and it will split your views evenly according to your `weight` value.

Read here more: [Layout weight](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Another option is to use `RelativeLayout` only, where you have free-hands on designing and placing your views within one single Layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Text view"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="DELETE" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:text="EDIT" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: **Try this one**